# Assigning NULL to element of big list takes a lot of time and RAM

Tags: r, list, null, ram

I have a list containing 7000 data.tables of 100.000 rows and 3 columns.
I saved the list as a RDS, left R, came back and reloaded it back in a clean session.
I have 10 GB of RAM free, but I cannot do any operation on this list.

The simplest one I can think of:

```
my_list[[1]] <- NULL
```

eats my 10GB of ram in 2 min, then returns the error:

```
cannot allocate vector of size 677 Kb
```

What I really want to do is remove the duplicates of all these tables, then stitch them all together, but I'm really confused about the way R uses the RAM here.

Comment: Break them in to chunks of 10 data tables, save it in hard disk, read chunks one by one, perform null operation on data table, save it on hard disk and combine them back into one big list, if needed.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to split it and see how it goes. Do you have any idea what happens with the RAM ? Is R really reassigning the whole list each time you change one element ?